# Why do some of the TextInput or StatusBar properties not work on Android?

Tags: android, react-native

I'm struggling with Android version of my simplest ever React Native app. 
Seems like Android ignores some of the props, namely `translucent` in `<StatusBar />` and, most annoyingly, `multiline` and `underlineColorAndroid` in the `<TextInput />`.

Here's the code, it's pretty straightforward:

```
<View style={[styles.main, {backgroundColor: background_color}]} >
    <StatusBar 
    barStyle="light-content" 
    translucent={true} /> 

    <View style={[styles.header, {backgroundColor: background_color}]}>
        <Button name='clear' disable={this.state.text} action={this.clearInput} />
        <Button name='run' disable={this.state.text} action={this.openFullScreen}/>
    </View>

    {
        this.state.fontLoaded ? (
            <TextInput 
            style={styles.input} 
            ref='input'
            onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text: text})}
            placeholder={this.state.placeholder} 
            value={this.state.text} 
            multiline={true} 
            placeholderTextColor={placeholder_color}
            returnKeyType='done' 
            blurOnSubmit={true}
            numberOfLines={5}
            autocorrect={false}
            underlineColorAndroid='transparent' />
            ) : null
    }
</View>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
main: {
  flex: 1,
  display: 'flex',
  flexDirection: 'column',
  alignItems: 'center',
  justifyContent: 'flex-start'
  },

header: {
    height: 88,
    width: '100%',
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'space-between'
  },

input: {
  width: '94%',
  flex: 1,

  fontSize: 50,
  lineHeight: 1,
  fontFamily: 'Roboto',
  fontStyle: 'normal',
  fontWeight: '900',
  color: '#ffffff',

  overflow: 'hidden',
  textAlignVertical: "top",
  //lame fix for Android
  //paddingTop: Platform.OS == 'android' ? 40 : 0,
},
});
```

This is what it looks like on iOS: 
[iOS-with-text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYyp5.png)

And this is the mess on Android: [android-with-text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKw9a.jpg)

As you can see, for some reason it a) draws the text on the top of the screen instead of top of the TextInput, b) doesn't do line breaks, overlapping all of the words on just 1 line (BTW I tried changing `textBreakStrategy` prop but to no avail), and с) still shows a white underline. Placeholder state on Android looks fine though (meaning placeholder is located right where it should be and has line breaks).

It's my first RN app and I used create-react-native-app to set up the project.

react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.47.2

Any advice would be much appreciated!

UPD: `lineHeight: 1` caused half of the trouble (not sure what its problem with `translucent` and `underlineColorAndroid` is though). NTS: never ever blindly  copy paste your styles from your web ReactJS app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of things. Multiline is not enough to enable the wrapping. You also need to use numberOfLines as a prop.

Also, I think your problem is just the height of the TextInput or the flex surrounding the TextInput.

And lastly, it could be that your style header view has either a top attribute or a position absolute that is messing with the view.

If this does not solve it, please post your styles.

Edit: Some of those styles could be messing with the height. Try starting with something more simpler like this:

```
input: {
  width: '94%',
  flex: 1,
  height: 60,  //-> Add this to make sure the text has a height instead of flex
  //fontSize: 50, -> This is huge, the text might not be able to show entirely. 
  //lineHeight: 1, -> Line height is not the amount of lines. Is the size. It should be around the font size, so either remove it or try setting this value to 50 like the font size. 
  fontFamily: 'Roboto',
  fontStyle: 'normal',
  fontWeight: '900',
  color: '#ffffff',

  //overflow: 'hidden', -> This might be messing with the header
  textAlignVertical: "top",
  //lame fix for Android
  //paddingTop: Platform.OS == 'android' ? 40 : 0,
},
```

Comment: Hey, I set numberOfLines to 5 earlier today but it didn't help :/ I updated the snippet with the stylesheet, please take a look.

Comment: Start with a simpler style for the input. Pretty sure some of that is messing with it. See my edited answer

Comment: Also, TextInput's do not like you :)

Comment: OH YEAH mere removing lineHeight did the trick. I think the problem was that CSS has `line-height: 10px` for absolute values and `line-height: 1` for relative values, and here in RN `lineHeight: 1` means 1px... Stupid mistake. Weird it worked fine on iOS though.

Comment: Awesome. Please consider accepting the answer so it does not stay unanswered :) Actually there is a bug in RN about the TextInput, multiline and lineHeight.